# Is there a way to access an RTSP feed on a remote camera that only has a local network RTSP URL?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, camera, ip-camera, rtsp

We have a IP CCTV camera connected to a 4G modem that connects it to the Internet. The manufacturer has provided us with an RTSP URL in the form of
rtsp://admin:password0@LOCALIP/cam/channel1, which as expected only works when my computer is also plugged into the modem.

Being a 4G modem with dynamic IP, we cannot access the camera via a normal RTSP link with a public static IP and port number forwarded through the modem.

This company also offers a Wifi camera with two beacons, but this would require a local switch to port forward each local camera IP to a static IP and setting up such a facility at each location we require CCTV is not really a solution. The other option is the use of a public static IP 4G SIM card for each modem which is reasonably expensive at scale.

My company wants to connect the video feed directly to our website in preference to using the manufacturer's app, but I'm not really sure there's much in the way  of a cheap alternative. It's strange because the app doesn't seem (outwardly, at least) to involve any static IPs or port forwarding, so I'm at a loss what to do. Can anyone suggest a solution, perhaps in the way of just ripping the video feed from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a (for example OpenVPN) VPN between your office IP network and your camera network.  In that way it can be reached on the internal IP given to it by the VPN

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would using a VPN mean that either our customers have to connect to it to access the video or that we have to accept the feed in-office and then feed it to them after re-routing?

Comment: You would have to feed the customers after routing it through your office. (ie proxy it) if it is for external users.  If its only for people in the office they can see it directly.